# Re-positioning Bootstrap Carousel Caption

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was examining some past SO posts on this, but none of them helped me. My issue is that my captions are being pushed down to the point where they are no longer visible. This might be due to the varying sizes of my images. **How can I make it so that the captions show up right in the center (a fixed position) of the carousel for each slide regardless of what sized image I use?**

Here's what I have so far: http://www.bootply.com/KcWhRKSTxi

What I've tried: Previous SO posts mentioned to try margin-bottom for the captions. I've tried to play with the margin-bottom to push my captions up, but there are 2 issues: (1) This isn't responsive & (2) Some captions are lower than others. If you examine my bootply link, the caption in the second slider is visible because the image is the smallest (vertically speaking). In other words, even if I used margin-bottom, some captions will be higher/lower than others. In my current implementation, you won't see the captions on images 1 or 3 because they are being pushed below the 3 dots (image selectors).

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active peopleCarouselImg">
      <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440637475816-2e8bf1d4b6f3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=9000dbcc94e0bad6c5005dc1d867b105">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446645681877-acde17e336a9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=d8507a72935161039a62fbd8bba41283">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="peopleCarouselImg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1443808709349-353c8b390400?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=ae16ad1553fa2305bdab4a73f583a725">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




.carousel {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.carousel-caption {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you give your `.carousel-inner>.item` a max-height, then you could vertically align your `carousel-caption` content using top and transform css functions:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 600px;
}
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/H08K4Hxk3C

Edit: Fix CSS Selector & Syntax